# How to find out where a particular SS soldier was interned?

Tags: world-war-two

Is it at all possible to find out where a particular SS soldier was interned and what happened to him please?

Comment: It would help people trying to answer the question if you could document your research efforts so far.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on how seriously you want to know. Are you prepared to travel to Germany and to visit archives in person? And what do you have beyond the name?

- There is the [Bundesarchiv](http://www.bundesarchiv.de/DE/Navigation/Benutzen/Hinweise-zur-Benutzung/Militaerische-Unterlagen/militaerische-unterlagen.html), only partly digital, if you want unit histories.
- You might ask the [Suchdienst](http://www.drk-suchdienst.org/) of the Red Cross if they have a file (but they are supposed to help relatives find missing persons).
- Perhaps the best match might be the [Deutsche Dienststelle, formerly Wehrmachstauskunftsstelle (WAst)](https://www.dd-wast.de/de/unterlagen/akten-und-karteimaterial.html) with about 180k files on SS POWs.

Answer (score 2):

You could try googeling his name, title, whatever you know about him. Many times SS soldiers were repositioned, so maybe a lot of things are true. A lot of the time documents also were lost.

If you know where he lived before his duty you can search for the nearest training/drafting station, they will definetly have more information for you. If he got caught you will know on which front and by whom. Unless it was on the east in that case it's not very likely you will find more info.

If you need one to check archives, I live here. If they are not far away my own curiosity will make me help you look them up.

Good luck anyway!